# C sockets packet interception

Tags: c, sockets

I've been dealing with C sockets under Linux for a while.
My question is that is it possible to intercept (not sniffing) packets using sockets? If that's not possible, what's other methods to intercept packets on a OS that the destination IP address is not destined to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is exactly what sniffing is meant for. Why do you not want to use a sniffer? If you want to do this in your own code, look at using a `PF_PACKET` RAW socket in promiscuous mode , or use a library like libpcap.